# ignore IP while redirecting to www in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, seo, redirect

For `SEO` purposes, I have this part of code in my `web.config` file. It allows me to redirect all URLs to www format of my website's URL (for example it redirects `abc.com` to `www.abc.com`)

```
<rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true" >
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

Now my problem is it also redirects my website's IP to www format (I mean it redirects `123.123.123.123` to `www.123.123.123.123`)

How can I exclude my website's IP from this action? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Why not just be explicit  - `<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.foo.com" ....` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another negation rule to test the REMOTE_ADDR to the conditions.

```
<rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true" >
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true"/>
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="123\.123\.123\.123" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```